# Parameter is not valid in Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, winforms

My code doesn't throw any errors or warnings, and builds fine, but I cannot access the design view for some of my winforms pages.

In the Error list, it has a few messages which say "Parameter is not valid." inside the Designer files, and double clicking on the message always sends me to a line which includes `this.Controls.Add(this.label1);`.

This is happening on multiple forms and pages, and restarting visual studio or my entire machine has done nothing.

Comment: Did you delete a label called `label1` from a container at some point?

Comment: You probably need to start looking at your revision history to find the last good commit, then compare that with the next bad commit to see what changed.

Comment: What happens if you comment out those lines?

Comment: @ainwood that's what I thought too, but no. It was working last night, but this morning this problem has shown up on a page which I need to work on right now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If only git was being used in this project...

Comment: @Fildor sadly the errors on the Design view don't disappear.

Comment: It could be that events of your controls are using Runtime values even when in Design mode. See if `label1` has events implemented such as `OnPaint`, and if so, modify that to use `if (DesignMode) { /* something simple */ } else { /* your regular code */ }`.

Comment: @PeterB I just commented out code which I have in 3 base class files which modify the font at runtime, and the Design view now shows up. Looks like this was the correct answer. Why does winforms do this? Is there any benefit to having the runtime code affect the form in Design mode? Or is this more of a question for a different StackExchange site?

Comment: WinForms calls many of the control events that you define even when in Design mode. It is up to you to make sure that your events can handle both modes. I'm not too familiar with all that has to be taken into account, just that it is in general something to remember.

Comment: You can sometimes get more information by debugging one instance of Visual Studio from another. (1) Start two instances of Visual Studio. (2) In instance A, open the project with the errors, but do not yet open the design view. (3) In instance B, attach to instance A and select to stop on all exceptions in Debug|Windows|Exception Settings. (4) In instance A, attempt to open the faulty form. Hopefully instance B will now detect the error and show you where it is.

Comment: Well use whatever version control system you're using then. If you're not using version control by definition your project isn't important.